# Throw a ball up versus Throw up a ball

Tags: phrasal-verbs

For the phrasal verb *to throw something up*, as it to toss an object in the air, is this sentence OK, or is it interpreted as John vomiting out a ball?

(I) John threw up a ball

My intuition is that this would imply John ejected a ball from his stomach through his mouth.  To get the reading where John tosses the ball in the air, I would need the particle *up* to follow the object.

(II) John threw a ball up.

Comment: I would say he threw it upward or into the air.  To me, both sentences you wrote refer to vomit.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer phrase 2, but did a [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throw%20a%20ball%20up%2Cthrow%20up%20a%20ball&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrow%20a%20ball%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrow%20up%20a%20ball%3B%2Cc0).

It does indicate that phrase 2 is more common now, but as somewhat of a surprise to me, phrase 1 is before 1900 or so!

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence I could mean either, but real-world knowledge makes it more likely that it is about throwing rather than vomiting.

Your sentence II is possible, but I find it unidiomatic unless you are emphasising the "up". (eg *up* as opposed to *across*, or *up* meaning "to a person or place already mentioned as being above him").

Comment: Is it real-world knowledge that cancels out that reading, or is *throw up something* always implying *vomit*?

Comment: "Throw up a line" when trying to cross between 2 boats of different heights might not imply vomiting.  But usually throw up does mean vomiting.

Comment: There's also another idiomatic use of _throw up_ which is not about vomiting, eg _That run threw up several errors_.

Answer (score 0):

If the particke is an adverb, as in this case, and the direct object a noun, either word order is correct.